# How to properly debug node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line

I have typed this text in the cmd: 
`node --debug server.js`

It is result: `Debugger listening on port 8080`, then i need to  connect node-inspector, but cmd is <<frozen>>, and if i get out of debug mode (`node --debug server.js`), node-inspector won't be able to watch the page. How to <<unfroze>> cmd or how to turn on the debug in background mode?

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer!
The answer is very simple: i should open two cmd and run --debug on the first one and run node-inspector on the second one

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a smart debugging client than use Visual Studio Code for nodejs .

> Nodejs debugging with this is really cool.

Link : https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/?dv=linux64